# how can i search a member in a structure in C and print all the members?

Tags: c

We were asked to code a certain program in c that would enable a user to

- Add a student
- View all the students
- Search for a student and exit

with the use of structures. The program should act like a students' portal.
I have this 'tentative code' that when compiled, would print an error of Segmentation fault (core dumped). So this is how my code goes:

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct tag1{
    int day, year, month;
}Date;

typedef struct tag2{
    int number;
    char name[50];
    char course[30];
    Date birthday;
}Record;



main(){
    int choice, n, i=0;
    Record student[200];

    //printing of menu:
    printf("Choose from the menu:\n");
    printf("     [1] Add Student\n");
    printf("     [2] Search Student\n");
    printf("     [3] View All\n");
    printf("     [4] Exit\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);


    if((choice>=1)&&(choice<=4)){
        if(choice==1){

            printf("Enter student number:\n");
            scanf("%d", &student[n].number);    

            printf("Enter the name of the student:\n");     
            scanf("%[^\n]", student[n].name);

            printf("Enter month of birth:\n");
            scanf("%d", &student[n].birthday.month);

            printf("Enter day of birth:\n");
            scanf("%d", &student[n].birthday.day);

            printf("Enter year of birth:\n");
            scanf("%d", &student[n].birthday.year);

            printf("Enter course:\n");
            scanf("%[^\n]", student[n].course);

            n++;
        }
        if(choice==2){
        while(i<n){
            printf("%d\n", student[n].number);
            printf("%s", student[n].name);
            printf("%d/%d/%d", student[n].birthday.month, student[n].birthday.day,student[n].birthday.year);
            printf("%s", student[n].course);
            i++;
            }
        }
        }


    }
```

I was just half way through because I have no idea on how I will search for a student. Hope you have any suggestions for me to improve my code.

Comment: Where does the segfault occur? Can you run in debugger to find out?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, You use the `i` to iterate over students until you reach nth element.

So it should be `student[i]` not `student[n]`

This should work:

```
//...

while(i<n){ 

      Record current = student[i]; 

      printf("%d\n", current.number);
      printf("%s", current.name);
      printf("%d/%d/%d", current.birthday.month, 
                   current.birthday.day,
                   current.birthday.year);
      printf("%s", current.course);

      i++;
}
```

And yes, n should be initialized to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot initializing n (you probably want n=0).

Answer (score 0):

**To secrh for a student you can use like this **

```
int sno;
unsigned char flag=0;
printf("Enter student number to search :");
scanf("%d",&sno);
```

and then search this record to all record and when it matches to any record , displays that record.

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++) // where n is maximum number of records
{
     if(student[i].number == sno)
     {
         flag=1;
         /*** print all the member of student[i] ****/
         break;
     }
} // end of for loop
if(0==flag) { printf("\nSorry !!! Record not found with student number : %d\n",sno); }
```